# How do I include PHP classes having the same name as Drupal classes?

Tags: 7

I'm working on a custom module connecting Drupal and another website.
The other website is hosted on the same server so I decided to includes the classes in order to interract with it. (Using webservices is not an option for different reasons.)

Unfortunately I need to include one master file containing classes with the same name as Drupal classes; so I'm facing multiple errors.

Is there a way to use namespaces when we cannot force calls with `namespace\functioname()` inside includes files?

Comment: Are you asking if there's any way to have two un-namespaced (i.e. global-namespace) classes with the same name declared in the same PHP request? If so, then no, definitely not. Could you clarify what you need to know with regards to Drupal here? Sounds like you're asking a plain PHP language question that just happens to be in a Drupal site (not really something we'd deal with here). Either way, the only answer is: apply namespaces to the 3rd-party classes (or hack Drupal's core, but that would be a lot more work and bad practice)

Comment: As you said my need might be related to plain PHP issues.
However I'm dealing with two CMF which can't be hacked for bad practice of course; so I cannot add namespaces to the 3rd-party classes as you said.
I'm looking for a way (using Drupal hooks maybe) to deal with remote classes maybe before Drupal classes are called ?
Or as you said maybe my problem can only be solved with classic PHP, so I will dig into it.
(Sorry for my english and sorry for the big number of code terms in the first post)

Comment: Then you can't use them - unless you alter PHP as a language. You simply can't have two classes/functions/interfaces/traits with the same name within the same namespace, it's (rightly) prohibited by the language's design. Drupal can't do anything to help you here, the problem is at the language levle